# Format DateTime result before pass to the _datatable function in AliDatatableBundle

Tags: php, symfony, closures

I was reading [AliDatatableBundle](https://github.com/AliHichem/AliDatatableBundle) but didn't find anything helpful so here is my problem. This is the code in my `_datatable` function:

```
private function _datatable()
{
    return $this->get('datatable')
                    ->setEntity("ComunBundle:SolicitudUsuario", "su")
                    ->setFields(
                            array(
                                "Tipo de Tramite" => 'tt.nombre',
                                "No. Solicitud" => 'su.id',
                                "Tipo de Solicitud" => 'tr.nombre',
                                "Estado" => 'es.nombre',
                                "Fecha" => 'su.fecha_creacion',
                                "_identifier_" => 'su.id')
                    )
                    ->setWhere('su.usuario = :usuario', array('usuario' => $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId()))
                    ->addJoin('su.tipo_tramite', 'tt', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::INNER_JOIN)
                    ->addJoin('su.tipo_registro', 'tr', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::INNER_JOIN)
                    ->addJoin('su.estado_solicitud', 'es', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::INNER_JOIN)
                    ->setOrder("su.fecha_creacion", "DESC")
                    ->setHasAction(true);
}
```

As you may notice there is `fecha_creacion` field which returns to the view this `[object Object]` I'm suspecting it's a DateTime so I need to format it before send to the render/view but I have not idea in how to, any advice? I don't know if **Custom Rendering** as explained [here](https://github.com/AliHichem/AliDatatableBundle#-custom-renderer) is the solution but if it's I still having no idea around it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing in AliDatatableBundle can be resolved by making use of https://github.com/AliHichem/AliDatatableBundle#-doctrine-query-builder where you can write your symfony2 custom query making use of Doctrine.

And rendering the date object in the under twig file location (ali/datatable/Ali/DatatableBundle/Resources/views/Main/index.html.twig) by making use of [aoColumnDefs](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) you can see my example below in order to render date object in first column of your data table.

```
var $defaults = {            
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": null,
        "bPaginate": true,            
        "bLengthChange": false,
        //"aoColumnDefs": $aoColumnDefs, // you can comment this default one and write your own aoColumnDefs
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {"aTargets": [0],"fnRender": function(dateobject){ return dateobject.aData[0].date }},
            {"aTargets": [1],"fnRender": function(profile){ 
                //making decision based on different row data
                    if(profile.aData[1] == 1) 
                        return 'Admin'; 
                    else if(profile.aData[1] == 2) 
                        return 'Consumer'; 
                    else 
                        return 'Vendor'; 
                }
            },
            {"aTargets": [2],"fnRender": function(name){ 
                var $edit_url = strtr(
                "{{ path(edit_route , { 'id': "xx" }) }}",
                    { "xx": name.aData[{{fields|length}}-1] }
                );
                return "<a  style='float:right; margin-right:10px' class='dialog' title='edit'href='"+$edit_url+"'>"+name.aData[2]+"</a>"; 

                }
            }               
        ],
        "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {           
            var s = getWrapper();
            if( multiple && $('.dataTables_multiple',$(s)).length==0){
                $(s+' .dataTables_length').prepend(multiple_rawhtml);
            }
        },
        "bSort": true,
        "bFilter": {% if search %} true {% else %} false {% endif %},
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing":     '{{ 'Processing' | trans() }}',
            "sLengthMenu":     '{{ 'LengthMenu' | trans() }}',
            "sZeroRecords":    '{{ 'ZeroRecords' | trans() }}',
            // "sInfo":           '{{ 'Info' | trans() }}',
            // "sInfoEmpty":      '{{ 'InfoEmpty' | trans() }}',
            "sInfoFiltered":   '{{ 'InfoFiltered' | trans() }}',
            // "sInfoPostFix":    '{{ 'InfoPostFix' | trans() }}',
            "sSearch":         '{{ 'Search' | trans() }}',
            "sLoadingRecords": '{{ 'LoadingRecords' | trans() }}',
            "sUrl":            "",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    '{{ 'First' | trans() }}',
                "sPrevious": '{{ 'Previous' | trans() }}',
                "sNext":     '{{ 'Next' | trans() }}',
                "sLast":     '{{ 'Last' | trans() }}'
            }
        },
        "bAutoWidth" : false
    };
```

You can also set different twig files inside location (ali/datatable/Ali/DatatableBundle/Resources/views/Main) to have different twig files.
In your ownbundle twig file supply the argument main_template

{{ datatable({ 
        'edit_route' : 'RouteForYourEntity_edit',
        'delete_route' : 'RouteForYourEntity_delete',
        'main_template' : 'AliDatatableBundle:Main:myfile.html.twig',
        'js' : {
            'sAjaxSource' : path('RouteForYour_grid_action')
        }
    })
}}